# MailMessage from MailBee conversion from HTML to TEXT adds extra space

Tags: c#, .net, mailmessage

I am using MailBee to convert HTML to Text but it adds an extra space in the beginning of each line except from the first one.

For example I have this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style=\"font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;\"><br></div>
      <div style=\"font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;\">test</div>
      <div style=\"font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;\">test2</div>
      <div style=\"font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;\">test3</div>
      <div style=\"font-size:13px;font-family:Arial;\">test</div>
   </body>
<html>
```

(The html is in one line. I have changed it to multi line just for readability.)

When I use this code to get text

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage
 {
    BodyHtmlText = Html
 };
 message.MakePlainBodyFromHtmlBody();
 return message.BodyPlainText;
```

I get this result

```
\r\ntest \r\n test2 \r\n test3 \r\n test \r\n
```

As you can see, before test2, test3 and test, there is an extra space added.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't put images of code in your question, then we can't copu/paste to test and/or quote.

Comment: I am sorry. It won't happen again.

Comment: @PoulBak I have removed the images.

Comment: MailBee.NET library just preserves content, not all the details of formatting. If you need some specific formatting in plain-text, you should create this plain-text by yourself, not by converting it from some HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a simple regex to remove Spaces at start or end of line.
The regex:

```
^[ ]*|[ ]*$
```

It simply matches zero or more Spaces at either start or end of line.

You need to set the 'Multiline' option.

Then replace the Spaces with an empty string.

**How to use:**

```
message.BodyPlainText = Regex.Replace(message.BodyPlainText, "^[ ]*|[ ]*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Now your message will have Spaces removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, because this is a rich text editor, the user might intentionally have added space in the beginning of the line, so I can not just remove all spaces in this way.

Comment: @MikeMakos Doesn't your rich editor control itself has any means for plain-text retrieval?